# How to make window/form become active foreground?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm using Visual Basic 2010 Express.
I have a form that can be minimized.
There's also a tray icon.
I've coded it so that if you double-click on the tray icon, the form's FormWindowState becomes set to Normal; this restores the form to where was before it became minimized, but the form does not become the active window on my desktop.

How can I make the form become the active most foreground window? I've tried various functions that I can think of but no luck yet. Tried searching with various queries to try and find the right wording but no luck.

I'm new to Visual Basic - only started a couple hours ago.

Probably something simple but I can't seem to find the correct function or anything... Please enlighten me! Thanks.

**Edit for further info:**
Say I have the form/window open, and then I overlap said form with a window of another application. When I double-click my app's tray icon, I want my window to become the active window, bringing it to the front, but can't figure out how >_<

Comment: Thank you for adding more relative tags, David.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [Form.Activate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activate.aspx)

Comment: Seems you've deleted your previous comment, Michael... Form.Activate() ended up doing the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, whether it's minimised or hiding behind another application's window, it activates it and brings it to the foreground. Cheers.